# How to conceptually add polymorphism?

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism

I've got a group project that involves taking a Java program used to emulate an ice-cream shop and converting it into a GUI application.

The shop pre-loads 16 different ice-creams. There are workers in the shop as well as cashiers & stockers (*which both extend from worker, where cashiers have an int patience, and stockers have an int stamina*).

Workers (*and thus cashiers/stockers*) are able to serve ice-cream. Only cashiers can process orders, and only stockers can restock ice-cream (*each ice cream starts with 80 scoops*).

There is only one active cashier/stocker at a given time, and possibly a cashier/stocker on break. The workers are loaded from a file (*where each line explicitly states if it is a Worker, Stocker, or Cashier*) into their respective array lists (*whereby there's an ArrayList for Workers, an ArrayList for Stockers, and an ArrayList for Cashiers*).

I'm now finding it very complicated to convert this into a GUI having to mess around with 3 ArrayLists. I want to change the project to save all workers into one ArrayList of type Worker. However, a lot of the actions within the shop are already defined/executed assuming three different ArrayLists.

Changing the code to load the whole Worker file into one ArrayList of type Worker is simple. However, how can I conceptually change the rest of the functionality of the shop to work with one ArrayList?

For example - if I want to set the shop's active cashier to be Bill, how could I navigate the ArrayList to find only cashiers, then find Bill, then set him to be active?

I suppose what I'm confused about is how can I interact with an ArrayList of subclasses and know which type of subclass I'm interacting with at a given time? I'm aware of how to use instanceOf() but I feel like it extends (*no pun intended*) further than that?

Comment: Generally if you have to check for specific types then the polymorphism in the design is likely broken.  It's a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle.  The model itself should know what it needs to do when you invoke an operation that's common to all models.  For example, if "Bill" needs to begin his shift, then you would find the element in the collection with `Name` equal to `"Bill"` and would invoke an operation on that object, something like `beginWorking()`.  The object itself should contain the logic of what it needs to do.

Comment: So - let's say my Workers ArrayList looked like (where the letter denotes the type of class, Worker/Stocker/Cashier): [W, S, S, W, C, C]. If I started the shop and wanted to set the active cashier/stocker to their first instances in the ArrayList (so at index 1 for Stocker and 4 for Cashier) - and later on I pressed on a button to "Change Active Cashier/Stocker" - how could I go about showing all cashiers/stockers except the active one?

Comment: Having *zero* knowledge of your code, I can't really say how you'd show anything.  If I had a collection of Employee objects, I imagine I'd also have an object which coordinates their current work schedules.  Perhaps called a TimeClock object or something of that semantic nature.  It would maintain the state of current shifts and would know which Employees are currently working where.  The ArrayList is really just a repository of Employee objects, nothing more.  You fetch an Employee from it.  It shouldn't be used to coordinate shifts and other business logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you would iterate over an array of Workers when you want to call generic Worker actions (like `getPaid()` or `startShift()`). The implementations of these might vary according to the specific class (this is Polymorphism in essence), but they would be common to all `Workers`.

Without looking at your code, it seems unlikely you would get benefit from trying to call `Cashier` or `Stocker` specific methods from a Collection of Workers.

Answer (score 2):

I think that putting them all into a single collection is going to prove more problematic than keeping the separate lists.

As you mentioned, finding one of a particular type would be "messy".

If you have a lot of other cases where you need to iterate over all of the workers, consider either keeping them all in an additional collection just for that purpose, or creating a method that iterates over all three lists, that you can reuse.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like that

```
private void processCashiers(){    
    List<Cashier> cashiers = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Worker w : workers){
            if(w instanceof Cashier){
                cashiers.add(w);
            }
        }
    // do something with cashierers here
}
```

Basically creating a specified list locally and process it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds it would be easier to manage them as different arrays/objects for the worker types, and yet another object to manage them as employees.  Employees would not be an array, but an object containing pointers to all the different arrays, but could also process high level tasks, as well as display them on the GUI in a generic fashion.  Displaying them would be grouped by type, unless you need to display them by some other criteria (ordering from file), in which case you could return a (temporary?) array.  If you have the flexibility on the GUI, make worker type views/subviews that could handle anything specific to that object type.